# c# Stabilise complicated sort

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a complicated sort method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Performs an advanced sort on products using sortations
/// </summary>
/// <param name="products">The products to sort</param>
/// <param name="sortations">The sortation list</param>
public void AdvancedSort(List<JObject> products, List<Sortation> sortations)
{

    // Throw if we don't have our injected handler
    ThrowIf.ArgumentIsNull(() => _expressionHandler);

    // Get our value types
    GetTypesFromOperator(sortations);

    // Replace our variable expressions
    _expressionHandler.ReplaceVariables(sortations, products);

    // For each sortation
    foreach (var sortation in sortations)
    {

        // Sort our products by the sortations
        products.Sort((a, b) =>
        {

            // Get our values
            var fieldName = sortation.Field;
            var x = a.SelectToken(fieldName).ToString().Trim();
            var y = b.SelectToken(fieldName).ToString().Trim();
            var type = sortation.Type;

            // If both values are the same, skip the rest of this iteration
            if (x.Equals(y)) return 0;

            // If we have an expression
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortation.Expression))
            {

                // If we are checking for between
                if (sortation.Operator == "><")
                {

                    // Get our values
                    var values = sortation.Expression.Split(',');

                    // If we have 2 values
                    if (values.Length == 2)
                        return CompareBetween(values, x, y);
                }

                // If we are checking booleans
                if (sortation.Operator == "===")
                    return CompareBoolean(sortation.Expression);

                // If we are checking equals
                if (sortation.Operator == "=")
                    return y.Equals(sortation.Expression) ? 1 : -1;

                // If we are checking like
                if (sortation.Operator == "%")
                    return y.Equals(sortation.Expression, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? 1 : -1;
            }

            // If we get this far, do a switch on sortation types
            switch (sortation.Type)
            {
                case SortationValueType.Boolean:
                    return Boolean.Parse(x) ? -1 : 1;
                case SortationValueType.Number:
                    return CompareNumeric(x, y, sortation.Direction);
                default:
                    return string.CompareOrdinal(x, y);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I thought it was working correctly, but this line:

```
if (x.Equals(y)) return 0;
```

Is reordering my items even if they are the same. Turns out that this is by design because the **Sort** method is unstable.
I would like to stabilise my sort method, I can't really convert my method into linq **OrderBy** because my sort method is too complicated.

Does anyone know how I can stabilise the sort method?

Comment: Sort __is__ unstable. Go for Linq! [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx)

Comment: "I can't really convert my method into linq OrderBy because my sort method is too complicated." Yes you can -- `OrderBy` takes an `IComparer<T>`. You've written a `Comparison<T>`. You get from one to the other by using [`Comparer.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh737198).

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do that?